# JAVA - Problems with Override on Interface and Class

Tags: java, class, jenkins, interface, overriding

Salve...

some Problem for me in Java. I have generated an Interface and an Class implements this Interface. In the Interface i have declared one Method... and in the Class i will Override this. But not works! But don`t why....

See my example Interface:

```
public interface IMyClass extends IInterfaceA<IInterfaceB> {

public List<IInterfaceB> getMethod(Integer id); 

}
```

See now my Class File:

```
public class MyClass implements IMyClass {

@Override
public List<IInterfaceB> getMethod(Integer id) {
    return anything;
  }

}
```

---

Problem is... i think i make no mistake. And next - i surprise that i have another Interfaces and Classes with the same Logic - and it will work and make no Problems!

In my another Interfaces & Classes i don`t need to make the Class with implements the Interface an Abstract Class.

When i make an build... Jenkins will surprise me with this Message:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
>
> error: MyClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method getMethode() in IMyClass [ERROR]
> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype [INFO] 2 errors [INFO]

Comment: `getMethod` or `getMethode`?

Comment: Sorry... will means also in all Interface, Classes and Error Message getMethod() .... the Name of the Method in Interface and Class is 100% the same....

Answer (score 0):

Solved . The " solution " - was a build problem . After tens of Maven Clean Installs and re- builds he has the connection interface and class savvy and it goes... oh men ;)